# What does the “word origin” mean?

Tags: dictionary, origin

I have a dictionary app that lists “Word Origin” in the entry. The word origin values I’ve seen have been XXXAX, XXXBX and XXXCX. What do those letters represent?

Update: a screenshot for reference

The app:
[image]

You can also see a number of examples [here](https://sites.google.com/site/asupernaturalaffection/home/the-great-renaissance-robbery).

Comment: Welcome to the site! More details would help here: What app is it? Is it a Latin dictionary? Can we see a sample dictionary entry? It's much easier to judge when one sees a bigger picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess that you're using [Whitaker's Words](https://mk270.github.io/whitakers-words/), since those look like Whitaker's origin codes.

Each letter in the code indicates something about the word: in order, they're `AGE`, `AREA`, `GEO`, `FREQ`, and `SOURCE`. The first indicates how early or late the word is attested; the second indicates what general topic it's related to; the third indicates where in the world the word was found; the fourth indicates how frequently the word appears in corpora; the fifth indicates which source Whitaker took the word from.

For all of them, a value of `X` means "not known" or "not applicable". So none of the words you've been looking at are associated with a specific time period, area of interest, or region, and Whitaker didn't note his sources for them. But the fourth letter tells you roughly how common the stem in question is: `A` is more common than `B`, `B` than `C`, and so on.

A full description of all the abbreviations and their meaning can be found [here](https://mk270.github.io/whitakers-words/dictionary.html).